# Data Mining in Lisp

Tags: statistics, lisp, common-lisp, data-mining

I'm looking for a way to accomplish data mining tasks in Common Lisp; does anything exist that would make this possible? I found [Incanter](http://incanter.org/) for Clojure, but I have to stick to Common Lisp for the task at hand.

Comment: Well, the readme says "SOMEWHAT BROKEN", and the last commit is a few months old, but [common-lisp-stat](https://github.com/blindglobe/common-lisp-stat) might be worth a look. (I wanted to check it out a few months ago, but didn't have the time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are libraries I use often and think helpful:

- [GSLL: GNU Scientific Library for Lisp](http://common-lisp.net/project/gsll/)
- [LLA: Lisp Linear Algebra (blas and lapack bindings)](https://github.com/tpapp/lla)
- [Gabor Melis' ML Libraries(svm, svd, statistics, etc)](http://quotenil.com/git/)

There are a lot more [listed on cliki](http://www.cliki.net/mathematics) that I haven't had a chance to evaluate.

Comment: Is there documentation available for Gabor's libraries?

Comment: Nothing beyond doc-strings that I'm aware of.  Just examine the exported symbols and dive into the source, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd also add [common-lisp-stat](https://github.com/blindglobe/common-lisp-stat) into the mix

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, data mining is a huge field

For statistics, I would also check out:

- Tamas Papp's other libraries as well as LLA. In particular cl-random, cl-slice& Cl-num-utils  useful stuff.
- Mirko Vukevic has a nice implementation of data tables

For the moment I would not worry too much about common-lisp-stat. To say that its pre-alpha would be an understatement. However that will change Real Soon Now, as i intend another round of development

for data munging - Alain Picards CSV (or the many variants thereof, or Pascal Bourgignon's implementation).

Check out the http://www.cliki.net/database page for various database clients.